# What type of engine/motor is used in aircraft APU?

Tags: apu

Is the APU a mini-jet engine, or some other type of motor? I know its purpose is to provide power when the engines are off, but what kind of motor/engine is used to generate the power?

I assume this differs from one type of aircraft to the other, but for the purposes of narrowing down the responses - I would like to know specifically about Boeing's APUs lets say on the 737NG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the only fuel available on an airliner is kerosene, the APU is a kerosene-powered jet. Using a different and maybe more efficient type of engine would require an independent fuel system, which does not make sense for the small savings possible.

From the [737.org](http://www.b737.org.uk/apu.htm) page on APUs:

> There are many different APUs available for the 737. The most common
>   is the Garrett GTCP (Gas Turbine Compressor [air] Power unit
>   [electrics]) 85-129. This was standard for the series 1/200 but when
>   the -300 was introduced it was found that two to three times the
>   energy was needed to start the larger CFM56 engines. Garrett produced
>   the 85-129[E] which had a stretched compressor, ie the impellers were
>   lengthened and the tip diameters increased. When the 737-400 was
>   introduced, even more output was required and Garrett produced the
>   85-129[H]. This has an Electronic Temperature Control which limits hot
>   section temperatures depending upon demand and ambient temperatures.
>   By 1989 the 85-129[H] was the most standard APU in all 737 models,
>   although there are actually 14 different models of the 85-129 in
>   service with 737s.

To answer your question about the 737 NG, it continues:

> Other APUs available are the Garrett GTCP 36-280(B) and the
>   Sundstrand APS 2000 on the 3/4/500; and the [Allied Signal GTCP 131-9B](http://www.deltatechops.com/mro-capabilities/view/category/apu)
>   for the NGs. The main difference between them is that the Garrett is
>   hydro-mechanical whereas Sundstrand and Allied Signal are FADEC
>   controlled.

Be sure to load the [737.org page](http://www.b737.org.uk/apu.htm), it has lots of pictures and data on the APUs.

Comment: You can modify a diesel engine to run on Jet-A. But I believe that a reciprocating engine would be heavier than the jet.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Yes, and it would need an additional compressor. You get that part almost for free in a jet. The fuel economy would be better, however.

Comment: @ratchetfreak "I believe that a reciprocating engine would be heavier than the jet." Based on some of the diesel blocks I've seen, I could imagine one being heavier than a B737-NG!  ;)

Comment: @ratchetfreak: You don't need to modify the diesel engine; they run just fine on jet fuel as is.